# Let authenticated users (non-admin) reorder uploaded images using the 4-way arrow

Tags: 7, media

Currently, the admin is able to reorder uploaded images (field), using the 4-way arrow, like so:

[image]

But other authenticated users(not admin) can only reorder images through "Show row weights":
[image]

but it gets tedious when there is more images. Is there a way to enable the 4-way arrow for them?

Comment: Check two things: 1) Are there any JS errors in your console?  2). Can you reproduce on a clean install? `drupal_add_tabledrag()` doesn't check permissions so if a user (authenticated or not) has access to create/edit the content they should have access to table drag.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell yes you are right, it worked on a clean install. I am quite far into the project now. How do I use console with drupal?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell I looked into this and found that the 4way arrow is not showing because of the "bootstrap" & "variables" imports (I am using omega subtheme with sass+bootstrap). Any advice on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the draggable link is present, but only the bottom 10% of it, and the 4-way icon does not get rendered, even though the background is set in css.

This problem is due to the import of scaffolding in the the bootstrap scss file.